# 400 Bad Request on API call

Tags: python, api, http

I am currently working on getting some data from an API but am having issues with some requests.

The current call and a few others that are similar do not seem to be working, while others do (except these don't use the "payload" argument). I am using the same examples in the documentation so not sure why these aren't working.

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.mindbodyonline.com")

payload = ""

headers = {
    'Api-Key': API_KEY,
    'SiteId': SITE_ID,
    'Authorization': TOKEN
}

conn.request("GET", "public/v6/sale/giftcards", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
print(res.status, res.reason)
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Returns

```
400 Bad Request
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "public&#47;v6&#47;sale&#47;giftcards", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;e4311402&#46;1603655296&#46;0
</BODY></HTML>
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are missing `'Content-Type': "application/json",` in your headers dict according to the documentation. Does putting that entry in help?

Comment: I had tried that as well and still returns same error. I think it is something with it returning it as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

solved, it was wrong on documentation. Needs to be "/public/v6/sale/giftcards". It was missing the first "/".